# Get aws rightsizing recommendations using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I tried to get aws rightsizing recommendations through cli by using *get-rightsizing-recommendations* cli command. But it didn't work. Is anyone has an idea what is the correct cli command to get aws rightsizing recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `aws ce get-rightsizing-recommendation --service AmazonEC2`

`-- service` option is required and only valid value is `AmazonEC2`

I think you confusing about 1st and 2nd command i used. You can find that in the [AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ce/get-rightsizing-recommendation.html) Documentation. Where each Synopsis are inside the square brackets top of the page.

In the [Options](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ce/get-rightsizing-recommendation.html#options) Section, you can also find additional options that we can use with the `get-rightsizing-recommendation` command.